# Sonar does not accept null check via method

Tags: c#, methods, sonarqube, null-check

Sonar does not accept the control when we check for null via method. What can be the solution?

It only accepts when you do as follows:

```
if (callID == null) 
{
 throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callID));
}
```

It doesn't see it when I do it like below.

```
private static void a(string callID) {
            if (callID == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callID));
            }
        }
```

Is this a general problem for sonar?
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A link to the error/warning (because you say "does not accept", it should be an error) to the notice that Sonar provides, like: https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-125, or just `S125` for the code that is produces by Sonar, would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

I contacted the sonar team and they said this problem occurs with older versions.The version I am using is 4.30 and they asked me to upgrade it to 6.1.So,problem solved.